# angularjs v1.5.8 global dynamic alert message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to create a bootstrap alert message in one place and dynamically set the message and messageType from any where in my angularjs app.

I currently have a  method that does this but, for me to call it on every controller I would have to copy and paste the code on to the every view and controller. And that is not proper code reuse.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.widgets')
    .directive('alertMessage', alertMessage)
    .controller('AlertController', AlertController);

  /* @ngInject */
  function alertMessage() {

    var directive = {
      link: link,
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'app/widgets/alertmessage.html',
      scope: {
        messageType: '<',
        Message: '@',
        hasError: '<',
        show: '<',
      }
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {


    }
  }

  AlertController.$inject = ['coreservice', '$scope'];

  function AlertController(coreservice, $scope) {

    console.log();

  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-strict-di>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <base href="/" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="Main">


  <div ng-if="$ctrl.show" ng-class="{ 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in':$ctrl.hasError, 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in':!$ctrl.hasError }" role="alert" ng-hide="$ctrl.closeAlert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" ng-click="$ctrl.closeAlert=true"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    <h4>{{$ctrl.Message}}</h4>
  </div>


  <div ui-view></div>

  <!-- Bootstrapping -->
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <!-- Reusable Modules -->
  <!-- core module -->
  <script src="app/core/core.module.js"></script>
  <script src="app/core/core.service.js"></script>
  <!--widgets/shared-->
  <script src="app/widgets/widgets.module.js"></script>
  <script src="app/widgets/alertmessage.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can save your time with this lib: https://github.com/alexcrack/angular-ui-notification

Comment: I have looked at libraries but, they don't show me how to dynamically change the message and message type from any other controller. I currently am referencing this library: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#alert . This doesn't work like I want it to. So I am trying to create it myself.

Comment: You have to write interceptor for global alerts. Look at this: https://github.com/alexcrack/angular-ui-notification/issues/29

Comment: The interceptor is specific to http responses. That's not what I am looking for. I want to be able to call a method that takes a message and a messageType and show a bootstrap alert message from any controller. I currently have a  method that does this but, for me to call it on every controller i would have to copy and paste the code on to the view and the controller. And that is not proper code reuse.